# Is it possible to keep TDs fluid while TABLE is fixed?

Tags: html, css, electron

**Edit 08.02.2017:**
I don't need to support every browser, since I'm working with the latest `electron-framework`. Which runs on `Chromium 56.0.2924.87`

---

I've got an editable `table` which is initialized with some data before the user can edit it. Since I want to print that table later on in A4 Format it mustn't exceed a given width.

My problem now is that if I use

```
table-layout:fixed;
width:100%;
```

the editable `TDs` won't be fluid anymore. Of course I am aware that this is a paradox, something that is `fixed` can't be `fluid`...

However I'm sure that in 2017 there must be a way to achieve a `fixed table` with `fluid td`.

Here is an example without the fixed table: https://jsfiddle.net/stjkd2xs/

As you can see as long as you use little words, the `table` will not exceed it's parent. The `TDs` are `fluid`. However if you start writing a long word the `table` breaks through it's parent.

Here is an example with a fixed layout: https://jsfiddle.net/jdedo87z/

In this example the `table` will use all of the parents width, which is good. But the `TDs` will have a fixed width themselves, which is not good.

I want to achieve somehow `TDs` which act `fluidly` in a `fixed table`.

- Is there a pure CSS way of doing this?
- Is there any other way of solving this paradox?
- Sidenote: I was thinking about removing the `table` completely and use `divs` instead...

Looking foreward for your advises.

regards, Megajin

Comment: Thus one of the reasons one should never use tables for layout. If you are using divs to replicate tables then you might want to reconsider what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Rob I'm not using `tables` for layout. The `tables` are there for to show data which should be put in `tables`.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how tables work...

But you could try something like this:

```css
.freak-box{width:300px; height:300px; border:1px solid red;}
.phreak{position:relative; max-width:400px; margin-right:100px; border:1px solid blue;}
.squishy-inside{position:absolute; width:100%; display:inline;}
```

```html
<div class="phreak">
  <div class="freak-box">
    <div class="squishy-inside">
      When Tom came home from the park, he opened the door to his home and found something was amiss. A lamp was knocked to the ground and there was strange noises coming from the kitchen. He felt his chest tighten as he thought of his wife, Sarah, was she ok or was she in there... where the noises were?
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I get it correctly the `quishy-inside` width will be ignored, that's not what I want to achieve.

Comment: Consider that what you are asking for may not be logically consistent with how browsers currently function, but if you're willing to accept that a bit of sleight of hand is needed, my solution will work for you.

Comment: Yes, that might be true. However it will disturb the userexperience in the frontend. Since I'm working with the latest electron-framework I do not need to support most browsers.